# Mysql case statement not returning appropriate message after case evaluation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am selecting engineStatus field from car table, the query looks like so :-

```
select engineStatus from car LIMIT 1
```

car table column can have values 1 or 0.
Assuming engineStatus is set to 1, the above query will return 1.

I want to return `ON` if engineStatus = 1 or return `OFF` when engineStatus = 0

I've tried below query, but SQL throws an Error

```
SELECT ( case engineStatus = 1 then SET engineStatus = 'ON' else SET status = 'OFF') FROM `car` WHERE 1
```

Mysql Says

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then SET engineStatus = 'ON' else SET engineStatus = 'OFF') FROM `car` WHERE 1 LI' at line 1
```

How can i achieve this in mysql ?

Comment: WHEN and END are missing

Comment: You miss WHEN and END. As well as you shouldn't use 'SET' here, inside the select

Comment: So you simply want to return ON instead of 1, or else OFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `WHEN` and there's no need `SET` here

The proper syntax is :

```
SELECT 
   ( CASE
       WHEN engineStatus = 1 THEN 'ON' 
       ELSE 'OFF'
     END
    ) AS status
FROM `car` 
WHERE 1
```

Comment: cool, works! I had implemented the same solution a couple of months ago, forgot to include the WHEN clause.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
SELECT ( case WHEN engineStatus = 1 then 'ON' else  
'OFF' END) FROM `car`;
```